# OpenMP private class member std::vector

Tags: c++, oop, parallel-processing, openmp, stdvector

I have a class member `std::vector<double> chi_` which I would like to use in a `parallel for` loop where each thread sees a different version of `chi_`. However, even when using `private(chi_)` it's clear that each thread sees the same value of `chi_`, not just from analysis of output, but from the address of `chi_` that each thread sees.

Is it possible to utilize OpenMP for a `parallel for` loop inside a class function on a class member variable such that each thread sees a unique version of that variable?

I compile and run my code using the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export OMP_NUM_THREADS=2

set -e

CC=clang++

$CC -O3 --std=c++17 -o test_rho.exe main.cpp
$CC -O3 --std=c++17 -DOMP -fopenmp -o test_rho_omp.exe main.cpp

./test_rho.exe > ser.txt
grep 'TID' ser.txt | sort -nk6,6 -nk3,3 > ser.tmp
./test_rho_omp.exe > omp.txt
grep 'TID' omp.txt | sort -nk6,6 -nk3,3 > omp.tmp

grep 'chk' omp.tmp | sed 's/chk//g' > chk.tmp
grep 'gen' omp.tmp | sed 's/gen//g' > gen.tmp
```

and the contents of `main.cpp` is below:

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <omp.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Wfn class
class Wfn {
    public:
        Wfn() { chi_.resize(nChis_); }
        std::vector<double> rhos(size_t nrhos);
        double rho(double x);

    private:
        size_t nChis_ = 120;
        void gen_chi(double x);
        std::vector<double> chi_;
};

// Pre-generate the array 'chi_' to reduce time complexity in rho calculation
void Wfn::gen_chi(double x)
{
    int tid = 0;
#ifdef OMP
    tid = omp_get_thread_num();
#endif
    printf("TID[%i] sees &chi_[0] = %p\n", tid, &chi_[0]);
    double xl, xm, xn;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nChis_; i++)
    {
        xl = pow(x, i % 3);
        xm = pow(x, i % 4);
        xn = pow(x, i % 5);
        chi_[i] = exp(-x) * xl * xm * xn;
        printf("TID[%i] (gen) iChi %3lu sees for %10.5f value %10.5e\n", tid, i, x, chi_[i]);
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < nChis_; i++)
        printf("TID[%i] (chk) iChi %3lu sees for %10.5f value %10.5e\n", tid, i, x, chi_[i]);
}

// Evaluate rho on a single value
double Wfn::rho(double x)
{
    gen_chi(x);
    double rhov = 0.0;
    for (size_t iChi = 0; iChi < nChis_; ++iChi)
        for (size_t jChi = 0; jChi < nChis_; ++jChi)
            rhov += x * chi_[iChi] * chi_[jChi];
    return rhov;
}

// Evaluate rho on multiple values in parallel
std::vector<double> Wfn::rhos(size_t nrhos)
{
    std::vector<double> rhos(nrhos);
    #pragma omp parallel for private (chi_)
    for (size_t irho = 0; irho < nrhos; ++irho)
        rhos[irho] = rho((double)irho / 1000.0);
    return rhos;
}

// Main
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Wfn wfn;
    std::vector<double> rhovs;
    size_t nrhos = 1000;

    rhovs = wfn.rhos(nrhos);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72754886/how-do-i-get-a-private-vector-while-still-using-functions-with-openmp/72764671#72764671) answer your question? (Replace global variable with class member variable :-)

Comment: @Laci - No. `firstprivate` does not solve this issue. I tried that. I have another version of this code which passes around a reference to `chi` variable which is not a member of the class and `firstprivate` works for that one, but not when using `chi_`.

Comment: Can you show us your updated code using references to `chi_`?

Comment: Gist below - it's a bit longer with some comments to show entering / exiting functions. But the idea is to create `chi` (as opposed to member variable `chi_`) inside of `Wfn::rhos` and then pass it around by reference, using `firstprivate` to ensure each thread gets it's own copy. Works as expected but not for `chi_`.

https://gist.github.com/drjrm3/fe3b4f9d4f4471bd53d9099d808e2140#file-main-cpp

Comment: Line 71, `_chi` should be `chi_`, line 31 should be deleted (as it prints the class member variable). If you use `chi_` at line 73, it should be OK

Comment: Agree with line 71 change. Everything else not as much. Even with the `firstprivate(chi_)` change you can see it still shows the same address for each thread.

The other point there is that I'm only doing that to show that `firstprivate` works for externally defined vectors to the class but not internally defined vectors (which is why I print both `chi` and `chi_` on 31). I can do it with externally defined vectors as shown in the gist but I want to do it with class member defined and that is what the question is focusing on.

Comment: If you use the `firstprivate` clause in one of your class member functions, it will only change what is happening in the structured block following the OpenMP construct. It does not change what is happening in a different function using the same member variable. If I understand well, that is your goal. You cannot do it. The only workaround is to privatize your class member and pass this local variable by reference and use this variable not the class member variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246136/discussion-between-drjrm3-and-laci).

Comment: You have one object. How can different threads see different versions of the one member of that one object? This completely does not make sense to me.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout - that very well may be the answer - that a member function cannot make private versions of its own member variables. The more I think about it the more this makes sense. I just can’t find an explanation detailing how this works and why it can’t be done.